# CASE WHEN in SQL with CONCAT

Tags: mysql, sql, concatenation, case-when

I need to create an extra column in a table with the field "WinterSeasonYYYY" of "SummerSeasonYYYY" being YYYY the year of that record.
Meaning that if the date is *01-01-2021* it will be considered **WinterSeason2020**, between March and August would be SummerSeason of the current year (*01-07-2021* would be **SummerSeason2021**), and after August would be winter season (*01-09-2021* would be **WinterSeason2021**)

So far I have been trying to assess this via CASE-WHEN:

```
SELECT *, 
CASE
WHEN MONTH(date) < 3 THEN
        extracted_year = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM (date)-1)
        CONCAT('WinterSeason',extracted_year);
WHEN MONTH(DATA_VENDA) BETWEEN 3 AND 8
        SET extracted_year = year(date)
        CONCAT('SummerSeason',extracted_year);
ELSE 
        SET extracted_year = year(date)
        CONCAT('WinterSeason',extracted_year);
END CASE AS SEASON
FROM CAMPANHAS;
```

Any ideas of where is the catch and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to subtract two months for the year calculation:

```
SELECT c.*,
       CONCAT(CASE WHEN MONTH(date) BETWEEN 3 AND 8
                   THEN 'SummerSeason' ELSE 'WinterSeason'
              END,
              YEAR(date - INTERVAL 2 MONTH)
             ) as season
FROM CAMPANHAS c;
```

Comment: This also works! 
And with fewer lines of code. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea but are trying to make it harder than it is, this should do the trick:

```sql
SELECT *, 
CASE WHEN MONTH(date) BETWEEN 1 AND 2 THEN CONCAT('WinterSeason',YEAR(date)-1)
    WHEN MONTH(date) BETWEEN 3 AND 8 THEN CONCAT('SummerSeason',YEAR(date))
    ELSE CONCAT('WinterSeason',YEAR(date)) 
END AS SEASON
FROM CAMPANHAS
```

Comment: Hi  @d0little ! Thanks a mil for your comment. 
Your code indeed works but it doesn't contemplate the requirement that when the Month is between January-March the Year in the `CONCAT` has to be `-1` from the one in the date. 
That is why I had 3 CASE-WHEN  in my query. 
Any ideas with that? 

Thanks again!

Comment: @LuciaRodriguez Ah no problems I've updated my original answer to reflect that